# add JList to JFrame

Tags: java, jframe, jlist

I use these lines of code to add a JList to my frame but it doesn't do the job.

```
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
model.addElement("one");
model.addElement("two");
JList list = new JList(model);
this.add(list);
```

Comment: add your some more code here please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you try this code

```
DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
model.addElement("one");
model.addElement("two");
JList<String> list = new JList<>(model);
this.add(list);
```